# jquery in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have included jquery in javascript but it is not working wt to do
i hv also included jquery in it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/home/aman/html/book_cricket.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11./jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery should run at the beginning

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11./jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/home/aman/html/book_cricket.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is the problem if javascript is above jquery

Comment: if you do not run at the beginning, jQuery can't detect its related code from `book_cricket.js`

Answer (score 2):

The browser reads the javascript files in the order you place them.
Try reversing them to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11./jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/home/aman/html/book_cricket.js"></script>
```